# Create a ggplot geom_boxplot when third variable=x

Tags: r, ggplot2

I think this is a fairly simple question, I just can't figure it out for the life of me.

I am making a boxplot using the following code;

```
ggplot(data, aes(gear, length)) + geom_boxplot() + xlab('Gear Type') + 
  ylab('Size (cm)') + ggtitle("Catch Characterization") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

This produces an aggregated boxplot for my entire dataset, I would like to be able to produce the same boxplot for two subsets of my dataset. Specifically I have another column "action" with either the character "D" or "K". For example MySQL mind wants to just add in a `WHERE` clause (however I know that is not how it works) such as;

`ggplot(data, aes(gear, length, WHERE`action`=`D`)) + geom_boxplot() + xlab('Gear Type') + 
  ylab('Size (cm)') + ggtitle("Catch Characterization") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))`

Edit, I am able to use facet_wrap to parse out and graph based on "action" however I am curious how I could just make one graph where of (length, gear) where "action = D". I know I can fairly easily just restructure my data just wondering if there is a simpler/quicker way to do so with the aggregated data set?

Edit again, think I figured it out by piecing a few things together, I ended up using this code and it seems to be giving me the appropriate graphs;

```
ggplot(aggdata[aggdata$action == "D",], aes(gear, length)) + 
geom_boxplot() + xlab('Gear') + ylab('Size (cm)') + 
ggtitle("Discard Characterization") + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: We don't have `data`, can you make a small reproducible example? Perhaps you want to add `group = action` to your `aes` (or `fill` to give them different colors)? Alternatively you can use facetting, e.g. by adding `+ facet_wrap(~action)`.

Comment: Yeah I had tried adding fill=action to aes which works but I would ideally like them in two separate graphs.

Comment: Which is why I suggested facetting, otherwise filter your dataset first. E.g. use `ggplot(dplyr::filter(data, action == "D"), aes(.....`, or look at `subset`, or use `data[data$action == "D", ]`.

Comment: If you want two separate graphs, then use Axeman's suggestion `facet_wrap(~action)` and it will separate the plots based on action values/levels

Comment: Thanks! I had never used facet_wrap but just got it to work.